# Mifare SMART Card Proper Identification Technique

Tags: c++, smartcard, mifare, identification

Ok so i have developed an application which communicates with Mifare Classic smart cards (contactless).

The application is going to be used for member identification.

The current way is was just writing a 16 byte value to block 4 of the card. I left all the keys as the default (FF FF FF FF FF).

But what is the proper way to develope this kind of system so that it is more secure? Should we use the UID of the card instead of writing our own user id to data blocks?

Also can someone explain how the keys are used etc.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to identify someone you may want to keep record of an ID but also of personal data, such as the name of the person. Other data also may be interesting depending on the purpose of you application.

The bad thing about recording personal data is that this card may be lost exposing that information to person that are able to read the card data. That's why you should change the keys of the card to improve security. This way, a third subject who wants to check the content of your card would have to find out the key value first and this, besides possible, is not so trivial.

To protect the key value instead of having it hardcoded you could work with tables loaded in the reader device. Some readers have a memory region (a EEPROM, for instance) dedicated to store key values and all you will have to do is to pass the index of the desired key.

I don't think that using the UID of the card is a good option, thinking in the maintenance of your system. If someone has to change the card you would have to update you database. The advantage of your solution is that you don't need to do absolutely no set up to the card...

So, if you don't want to record any data on the card and wish to use its UID for identification, don't even bother to change the key.

Hope that helps!